# Any statistics on Ubuntu versus Kubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

Does anybody know of any statistics on how many Ubuntu and Kubuntu users there are? I am aware of the distrowatch website (http://distrowatch.com/stats.php?section=popularity), and I'm looking for other sources.

**EDIT:**

Does anybody know of any statistics on how many **Gnome** and **KDE** users there are?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure this is a useful statistic. You can install KDE in Ubuntu, and you can install GNOME in KUbuntu, and switching between them is probably not that difficult.

Comment: You're right, I'll the update my question now.